# neo4j java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing xml file for /config/user-logs.xml/user-logs.xml

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, neo4j

I'm getting a **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing xml file for /config/user-logs.xml/user-logs.xml** error when deploying the following kubernetes deployment:

I'm using an init container to copy the neo4j configmap into the correct location as I was getting permissions issues.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: neo4j
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: neo4j-init
          image: myregistry/alpine:latest
          command:
            [
              "bash",
              "-c",
              "cp /tmp/neo4j.conf /var/lib/neo4j/bin/conf/neo4j.conf",
            ]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-file
              mountPath: /tmp/neo4j.conf
              subPath: neo4j.conf
            - name: neo4j-tmp-config
              mountPath: /var/lib/neo4j/bin/conf
      containers:
        - name: neo4j
          env:
            - name: NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT
              value: "yes"
            - name: NEO4J_CONF
              value: "/var/lib/neo4j/bin/conf"
          image: myregistry/neo4j:5.10.0-enterprise
          resources:
            requests: {}
          securityContext: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: neo4j-tmp-config
              mountPath: /var/lib/neo4j/bin/conf
            - name: myneo4j-volume
              mountPath: /var/lib/neo4j/data
              subPath: data
            - name: myneo4j-volume
              mountPath: /var/lib/neo4j/backups
              subPath: backups
            - name: myneo4j-volume
              mountPath: /var/lib/neo4j/import
              subPath: import
            - name: myneo4j-volume
              mountPath: /var/lib/neo4j/licenses
              subPath: licenses
            - name: myneo4j-volume
              mountPath: /var/lib/neo4j/plugins
              subPath: plugins
            - name: neo4j-tmp-config
              mountPath: /var/lib/neo4j/bin/conf/neo4j.conf
              subPath: neo4j.conf
            - name: logs
              mountPath: /var/lib/neo4j/logs
            - name: metrics
              mountPath: /var/lib/neo4j/plugins
      volumes:
        - name: myneo4j-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: myneo4j-pvc-volume
        - name: config-file
          configMap:
            name: neo4j-config
        - name: logs
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: metrics
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: neo4j-tmp-config
          emptyDir: {}
```

neo4j logs:

```
Installing Plugin 'apoc' from /var/lib/neo4j/labs/apoc-*-core.jar to /var/lib/neo4j/plugins/apoc.jar
Applying default values for plugin apoc to neo4j.conf
Changed password for user 'neo4j'. IMPORTANT: this change will only take effect if performed before the database is started for the first time.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing xml file for /config/user-logs.xml/user-logs.xml
at org.neo4j.logging.log4j.LogConfig$Builder.getConfigurationSource(LogConfig.java:341)
at org.neo4j.logging.log4j.LogConfig$Builder.build(LogConfig.java:304)
at org.neo4j.logging.log4j.LogConfig.createLoggerFromXmlConfig(LogConfig.java:136)
at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.setupLogging(NeoBootstrapper.java:289)
at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:142)
at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:100)
at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseEntryPoint.main(EnterpriseEntryPoint.java:19)
2023-09-14 11:16:48.807+0000 INFO [c.n.s.e.EnterpriseBootstrapper] Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
2023-09-14 11:16:48.819+0000 INFO [c.n.s.e.EnterpriseBootstrapper] Stopped.
```

Any idea how can I resolve this?